# appcmd set config appSettings - value with plus (+) is being converting to space

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, appcmd

I'm attempting to use appcmd to set an appSetting in web.config, the value for the appSetting contains a + symbol. When I run appcmd, the appSetting is created, but the + is converted to a space.

the appcmd i'm running:

```
"C:\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe" set config "Default Web Site" /section:appSettings /+"[key='Test',value='++ ++']"
```

the appSetting that is created:

```
<add key="Test" value="     " />
```

I've tried using %2b instead of + in the appcmd, this didn't work (it was converted to just the 'b' in the appSetting.

Does anybody have any idea how i can get a + symbol included in the appSetting when using appcmd?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using the unicode value of + which is `%u002b`?

```
"C:\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe" set config "Default Web Site" /section:appSettings 
/+"[key='Test',value='%%u002b']"
```

You need to add an additional % sign in order to escape the % in the unicode value.

That should result in the Test key having a value of +.

See:

- [Appcmd error setting MimeType + missing](http://forums.iis.net/t/1153819.aspx?Appcmd+error+setting+MimeType+missing)
- [Unicode Plus sign](http://unicode-table.com/en/#002B)